# Source of the quote "Life is a balance between holding on and letting go" from Jalāl ad-Dīn Muhammad Balkhī

Tags: quote-source, persian-language, rumi

There is a quote in the Internet which says: "Life is a balance between holding on and letting go". People cited it to Jalāl ad-Dīn Muhammad Balkhī (Rumi). My question is that:

- What is the exact address of this quote in his poems?
- What is the exact poem/sentence in Persian for that?

Comment: Are you sure this quote is from poetry? If so, the [[tag:poetry]] tag is applicable

Comment: I have wondered that too. It does not sound at all like Rumi's voice- it has a modern ring. I assume it's a paraphrase of something he wrote. But no place where I've seen this "quote" ever gives any more information- where in Rumi's writings it comes from, or what the nature of the context is.